# How do I turn on sticky keys from the CLI?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, accessibility

I'd like turning sticky keys on and off to be done from a script.  This is especially helpful to those not using kde/gnome/xfce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This script works:

```
$ cat $HOME/bin/sticky_keys 
xkbset exp -bell -sticky -twokey -latchlock -accessx -feedback -stickybeep -led 9999
xkbset bell sticky -twokey -latchlock feedback led stickybeep
```

(If you would prefer pressing Shift twice to mean "hold down shift" then change '-latchlock' above to 'latchlock')

For more and related information, you probably will like this wiki page:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accessibility/doc/Guide/Mobility

> Because of the missing tool 'xorgcfg' or 'xf86cfg' https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+ticket/506 in the ubuntu repository, you have to use the commandline tool 'xkbset'. Which isn't very user-friendly. You have to call 'xkbset' twice. By the first call, you set the expiry of the accessx settings. This is necessary, because there is a default timeout. By the second call, you can adjust the accessx settings themself. I don't know why, but in my settings, this was the required order!
>
> With xkbset -h you will get a help message.
>
> An example for setting the expiry of the accessx settings: `xkbset exp -bell -sticky -twokey -latchlock -accessx -feedback -stickybeep -led`
>
> You have to disable the expiry of all accessx settings you need. Because, if you set an explicit timeout with '0', you will cause a xorg runtime error.
>
> An example for adjust the accessx settings:      xkbset bell sticky -twokey latchlock feedback led stickybeep
>
> For further information refer to: http://www.xfree86.org/current/xset.1.html
>
> In the [Configuration example](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accessibility/doc/Guide/Mobility#example) below you see a setup for daily usage.

Comment: Please see if you can help out here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2129335&p=12574154#post12574154

Comment: This works in Xfce `xfconf-query -c accessibility -p "/StickyKeys" -nt bool -s 'true'`