# Disable Sticky Keys' "Locked After Being Successively Pressed Twice" Behavior

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, dconf, accessibility

I enabled sticky keys for ergonomics' sake. The default behavior under Unity and GNOME 3 is that a modifier (or layer) key will be "locked" after being pressed twice successively, and a third press will release the key. Sometimes I accidentally locked my Shift-key such that all the characters being typed thereafter are capitalized. This has been especially frustrating under a password prompt where the input isn't shown, hence I'm would like to disable this behavior.

After some Googling, it appears that Windows' *StickyKeys* has a **"Press modifier key twice to lock"** option. I tried looking for corresponding *dconf keys*, but to no avail. The closest I've come across is **"Behavior of sticky keys"**:

> Controls the behavior of sticky keys, e.g. modifier and layer keys.
>
> Groups of keys or single keys may be assigned individual behaviors.
>
> Valid groups are 'all', 'modifiers' and 'layers'. Individual keys may
> be specified by their ids defined in the .layout files.
>
> Valid behaviors are: 'cycle' (default), 'dblclick', 'latch', 'lock' as well
> as 'latch-lock-nocycle', 'dblclick-nocycle', 'latch-nocycle',
> 'lock-nocycle' and 'push'.

I tried all the *"behaviors"* (namely: **'cycle'** (default), **'dblclick'**, **'latch'**, **'lock'** as well as **'latch-lock-nocycle'**, **'dblclick-nocycle'**, **'latch-nocycle'**, **'lock-nocycle'** and **'push'**), yet the default behavior remains.

Spec:

> Ubuntu 16.04.1
>
> Unity

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue for a long time.

You can get the behavior you want by using *xkbset*. You can install it using *apt*.

```
sudo apt install xkbset
```

You can see the available options with

```
 xkbset -h
```

So instead of enabling sticky keys through the GUI. Use xkbset. The command given by [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120010/how-do-i-turn-on-sticky-keys-from-the-cli?rq=1) worked for me. Specifically the *-latchlock* option disables the unwanted behavior.

Currently I use

```
xkbset bell sticky -twokey -latchlock feedback led stickybeep
```

It seems like restarting your computer will forget the settings. Adding them as a startup script will work.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful to know this option. Do you know if there is also a way to cancel the sticky key when it is pressed twice? In windows pressing the windows key twice for example is equivalent to pressing windows once without sticky keys.

Comment: This tool is not well maintained, Also It does not work on machine (Gnome-Wayland, Fedora).

Comment: @Nur agreed. I stick to Ubuntu and with the switch to Wayland this no longer works.

Comment: @Nur You can change Ubuntu to use Xorg so you can still use this. Until something comes along which lets us use latchlock.

Comment: @gatoWololo check this https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/6852#issuecomment-1352547670