# Calling xkbset on startup

Tags: command-line, startup, xkb

I had the same problem found on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/880740/659322).

I found a solution by calling the command:

```
xkbset bell sticky -twokey -latchlock feedback led stickybeep
```

I would like to run on startup. I have tried the following things:

1. Calling it from my `.bashrc`. This *almost* works, but I have to open a terminal before the effects take effect system wide.
2. Directly call the command from `Startup Applications`. This does not work.
3. Create a `.sh` script which gets called from `Startup Applications`. This does not work, when I startup, nothing happens. I made sure the executable bit was set.

How can I add this command so it's called at startup?

Comment: Try to call it from `~/.profile` instead.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried it, restarted the computer, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I found was to simply call `gnome-terminal` as a startup program which will then execute it's `.bashrc` script.