# Use xkbset on Ubuntu 22.04 (Wayland Display Server)

Tags: gnome, keyboard, wayland, xkb

I use sticky keys due to accessibility issues. One problem with the sticky keys accessibility setting on Ubuntu is "latchlock" behavior. Where

> a modifier pressed twice will be locked

-xkbset man page

So accidentally pressing a modifier key **twice**, e.g. ctrl, will lock it leading to very frustrating and confusing behavior. The problem is explained in detail in [this previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880740/disable-sticky-keys-locked-after-being-successively-pressed-twice-behavior).

I can turn off this behavior through xkbset by using the `-latchlock` option as so:

> xkbset sticky -twokey -latchlock

However, this only works for Xorg. Since Ubuntu has switched to Wayland on newer releases. I'm not sure how to make this work.

I have found this question for using setxkbmap in Wayland. Where [the answer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/looking-for-alternative-for-setxkbmap-in-wayland/3380/2) shows the use of dconf + xkb-options:

> dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:swapescape']"

But I am not sure how to do something similar for xkbset.

So far my solution has been to switch back to Xorg.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry. I meant to say 22.04 Jammy. Title has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/6852#issuecomment-1352547670